# How I can have behavior RadioGroup SingleChoice for 2 or more checkbox on android?(at here for 2 checkbox ,specially)

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-group, android-checkbox

Hello stackoverflow friends.  I am new by android and I have a simple question that bothers me!
I have 2 CheckBox(CheckBoxAutomat and CheckBoxManual for example) . I want have like RadioButton group of type `SingleChoice behavior  for my checkBoxes`. I write this code but it has wrong result for me.
How I can have behavior RadioGroup SingleChoice for 2 or more checkbox(at here for 2 checkbox ,specially)?
Code:

```
               CheckBoxAutomat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
               {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(CheckBoxManual.isChecked())
                    { 
                            CheckBoxManual.setChecked(false);



                    }

                }
             });
               //..............................
               CheckBoxManual.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
               {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(CheckBoxAutomat.isChecked())
                    { 
                        CheckBoxAutomat.setChecked(false);


                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: CheckBoxes are meant for **multiple choices**, RadioButtons for **single choice**. You should really use RadioButtons. If you want to **CONFUSE YOUR USERS**, then you can **dress up your RadioButtons as if they where CheckBoxes**. But I call this **TRANSVESTISM**...

Comment: @Tobor I didnt like the defualt style of checkoboxes,while I needed radibutton surely.So I put radioGroup on my app and then change android:button with a checkbox_selector(with my favorite pictures ) which I created it.thank u for your thoughtful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question because I didnt like the defualt style of checkoboxes,while I needed radibutton surely.So I put radioGroup on my app and then change android:button with a checkbox_selector(with my favorite pictures ) which I created it. a cb_selector like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked2" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked2" />
</selector>
```

this must write in a xml file in drawable forlder. 
then i write @drawable/cb_selector in Button property for each radiobutton in my radioGroup.